# How do I prepare my hyacinths for planting out?

Tags: bulbs, planting

I received a couple of hyacinth bulbs in small pots that have flowered nicely, and I'm wondering what the best way to prepare them for planting out in the spring is.

They have 8 inch stalks with flowers, which are now starting to look a little weary. Should I just pop the bulbs outside now? Or perhaps plant them, or possibly even remove the stalks and just plant the bulbs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait until the foliage yellows, then remove the plants from the pots, trim off all the tops and roots. Plant them 4-6" deep if you have a sandy soil, slightly more shallow if you have clay. Cover the soil with 1" of a straw-type  mulch and tamp down. It should then need no further attention until spring.